# Is iOS capable of accessing and manipulating files on a Windows network file share?

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm planning an app for work and venturing into potential features which I've not used before.

Essentially I need to be able to access files on a network share, read, write and delete files as well as amend the file names. As a pretty closed platform I'm not sure whether iOS is capable of such a thing and if it is, what features should I look for to begin researching?

My Google-Fu hasn't come up with anything thus far so hopefully looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no native support for CIFS/SMB onios, but there are a few open source CIFS libraries that turn up in a google search.

Comment: I know this isn't very secure, but I'd personally create an ASP.NET app on your target Windows Server, or a different Server on the domain. Create web services exposed, and make an iOS app with UIWebView. You can do RPC calls from the web service that do WMI/ADSI/File System manipulation. You can prompt for domain credentials, and do remote calls essentially is the gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't very secure, but I'd personally create an ASP.NET app on your target Windows Server, or a different Server on the domain. Create web services exposed, and make an iOS app with UIWebView. You can do RPC calls from the web service that do WMI/ADSI/File System manipulation. You can prompt for domain credentials, and do remote calls essentially is the gist.

You could expose the web app so that your app can access it from local network, or URL. If you were to access it from outside I'd suggest using some secure credentials in Windows/IIS.

Some years ago I created a "mobile-friendly" web app that allowed me to manage servers, perform RPC, and do basic Active Directory queries. Also allowed file listing and deletion/moving/copying with some creative scripting. It was essentially a ASP.NET/C# web app that loaded in a iPhone app. UIWebView in iOS was a able to load it, used AJAX and some other client side scripting that looked decent. You'd essentially have to make sure that your web app renders properly in Safari/UIWebView (which is bastardized safari).

Here's a link to a demo of what I created:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czXmubijHwQ&t=12s

I ran it in a browser, but it'd run from my PSP, Android test devices, iPod Touch, Blackberry, etc.